# Bohemia Interactive's bio2s format

Tags: scripting

Does anyone have specifications for the bio2s scripting language from Bohemia Interactive? They develop Operation Flashpoint, Armed Assault (ArmA), and Virtual Battlespace.

These scripts are sometimes called O2 or Oxygen scripts and are used in their terrain and modeling tools. Oxygen is Bohemia Interactive's modeling tool.

I found additional examples of the format in [this VBS2 tutorial](http://developer.vbs2.com/onlinehelp/Content/Adding_Models/How_to/AMHT_Thermal_Imaging_How.htm) and this [ArmA forum thread](http://forums.bistudio.com/archive/index.php/t-70517.html).

EDIT: I clarified the purpose of the bio2s format and provided some links to examples.

Comment: I have found several code examples online, but still cannot find a specification document or a general explanation of the features of the language.

Comment: Initially I was going to direct you to Bohemia Interactive's wiki entries on scripting (http://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Category:Scripting_Topics) but it seems as if they are still under development. :/

Comment: @Ari Patrick: Thanks for your help! Those wiki entries seem to describe the SQF format which is used for runtime behaviors. I found another [SQF reference](http://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax) in that same wiki. However, I am interested on the bio2s scripts used in their terrain and model generation tools. I found examples in [this tutorial](http://developer.vbs2.com/onlinehelp/Content/Adding_Models/How_to/AMHT_Thermal_Imaging_How.htm) and this [forum thread](http://forums.bistudio.com/archive/index.php/t-70517.html) where they call these files Oxygen or O2 scripts.

Comment: A few more examples from the [Armed Assault Info forum](http://forum.armedassault.info/index.php?showtopic=1392&mode=threaded&pid=32162).

Comment: I'd suggest you'd do better actually asking a question (rather than just searching for existing answers) at the official forum's editing section: http://forums.bistudio.com/forumdisplay.php?f=92  There is a wealth of knowledge in the BI community... and most people are very willing to share their findings.  A number of community-made O2/Visitor scripts have been made for different purposes, so the knowledge is definitely available there.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is what you´re looking for:

[Oxygen 2 Manual](http://developer.vbs2.com/onlinehelp/)

**From the scripting section**: For those who would like to explore the possibilities available in O2 scripting, a command reference can be found at P:\docs\oxygen2 comref\comref.html.